# Intellij Idea often doesn't resolve Maven Dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Whenever I add any dependency to the Maven - pom.xml and try to use the library in Intellij Idea(Community Edition), it doesn't recognize the dependency. Tried to rebuild the Project from Build -> Rebuild Project, but it doesn't works.

Comment: First which version of intellij do you use? Furthermore turn on automatic reload...`Toggle Auto-reload mode` ... then any change in pom will automatically being loaded...

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)

Build #IC-203.5981.155, built on December 1, 2020

Runtime version: 11.0.9+11-b1145.21 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Current Desktop: GNOME

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise, will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though we add the dependency directly to the pom.xml and rebuild, Intellij-Idea doesn't often recognize the addition. You can fix this by

```
**Right Clicking the pom.xml in Intellij-idea -> Maven - Reload Project.**
```